# Parsing in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

I have an SQL table which has a cell like this :

> Outdoor pool, security, water tank

I need to convert that cell to this :

> - Column Outdoor pool =>  1
> - Column indoor pool => 0
> - Column security => 1
> - Column watertank => 1

I have no idea how to do this. I don't want you to do this for me. But please give me some pointers on this.

Please tell me how I can parse that column and generate new columns and fill those columns. Thanks.

Comment: Well you can create a new column of type `bit` (if you only want to use 1 or 0) and write a simple update statement with a `case when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `like`:

```
select (case when col like '%outdoor pool%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_outdoorpool,
       (case when col like '%indoor pool%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_indoorpool,
       (case when col like '%security%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_security,
       (case when col like '%water tank%' then 1 else 0 end) as has_watertank
```

Comment: Should I create a new table to fill with 0 and 1s? Thanks.

Comment: @jason . . . If you want to save the values in a table, then you will need a table with appropriate columns -- and use `update` or `insert` to populate it.  You can also use computed columns instead.

Comment: Adding delimiters will prevent confusion with overlapping entries, e.g. "eat-in kitchen" and "guest eat-in kitchen": `case when ', ' + col + ',' like '%, outdoor pool,%' then 1 else 0 end ...`. Note that this requires either consistency in the comma-space usage or replacing all instances of comma-space with a comma before searching the string.

Answer (score 0):

using PATINDEX may be useful as well
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx